# Load CMV with panes closed

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I'm using CMV as a template for my app, I am using the left and top pane, however I need the app to load with the panes closed, is there any way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with the `open` property in the panes config in `viewer/config.js`. Here's an example from one of the applications I built for a client:

```
panes: {
    left: {
        open: 'none', // using false doesn't work
    },
    top: {
        id: 'sidebarTop',
        collapsible: true,
        region: 'top',
        open: 'none' // using false doesn't work
    }
},
```